# How to load information in two columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

**Question 1**: The file *phone.txt* stores the lines in the format *code:number*

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
data = pd.read_csv('phone.txt', sep='\t', header=None)
data.to_sql('post_table', con, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I want to load all the data from the *phone.txt* file into the *database.db* database. But I have everything loaded in one column. And I need to load in two columns:

1. code
2. number

How to do it?

**Question 2**: after downloading the information to the database, how can I find the *number* by *code*? For example, if I want to find out what *number* *code = 7* (answer: 9062621390).

Comment: Can you please show what's in your `data`? Because chances are your dataframe has only one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

In your example pandas is not able to distinguish between the `code` and the `number` since your file is `:`-separated. When reading your file you need to change the separator to `:` and also specify columns since your `csv` doesn't seem to have a header like so

```
data = pd.read_csv('phone.txt',
                   sep=':',
                   names=['code', 'number'])
```

**Question 2**

After putting your data to the database you can query it as follows

```
number = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT number FROM post_table WHERE code = (?)',
                           con,
                           params=(code,))
```

where `con` is your sqlite connection.

Comment: TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'